# Chrome Extension- Change download folder for specific download

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just started to develop chrome extensions.
I want to create an extension in order to change the download folder for a specific download.

Can I do such thing?
if not,How can I change the default download folder before the downloads begin and then return it to the original value after the download ends?

Answer (score 13):

You can't change the base Downloads folder - this setting is not anyhow exposed.

However, with [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) you can put files in a *subfolder* of the user's Downloads folder.

You can either initiate the download yourself with `chrome.downloads.download` or use `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` request to intercept downloads from other sources.

You need to provide a relative path as a suggested name, e.g. `"special/filename"` to save into a subfolder `special` inside the Downloads folder.

Comment: is it possible to get the current base download folder path?

Comment: @user2720864 I don't see any way to do it before the API can provide you with at least one DownloadItem (which then has `filename` as an absolute path). But if your concern is letting the user find a file, look at `show` and `showDefaultFolder` methods.

Comment: I am sorry to reply this late. I just wanted to explore the options before making any comments here. My main intention is to get the full path once chrome download any files. `showDefaultFolder` opens up a new window where the file has been downloaded... I've also tried to use `chrome.downloads.search` API but without any luck. Any advice please

Comment: @user2720864 You can get a DownloadItem through one of the events, such as `onCreated` or `onChanged`, and read the full path from there.

Comment: Thank you, I will update my findings here. Appreciate your help

Comment: If you still need help with this, make it a proper question. It's not appropriate to do so in comments.

Comment: "special/filename" doesn't seem to work. The file is getting downloaded to the default download folder only. I need to make it download in a specific folder

Answer (score 3):

**Not an answer to the question** but there is a Chrome Extension that can do it.

[RegExp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regexp-download-organizer/oamembonjndgangicfphlckkdmagpjlg)